# Setting datatypes when writting parquet files with spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I’m reading some data from an Oracle DB and storing it in parquet files with spark-3.0.1/hadoop3.2 through python api.
The process works, but the datatypes aren’t maintained, and the resulting types in the parquet file are all “object” except for date fields.

This is how the datatypes look after creating the dataframe:

```
  conn_properties = {"driver": "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver",
                       "url": cfg.ORACLE_URL,
                       "query": "select ..... from ...",
                       }

  df = spark.read.format("jdbc") \
        .options(**conn_properties) \
        .load()

df.dtypes:
[('idest', 'string'),
 ('date', 'timestamp'),
 ('temp', 'decimal(18,3)'),
 ('hum', 'decimal(18,3)'),
 ('prec', 'decimal(18,3)'),
 ('wspeed', 'decimal(18,3)'),
 ('wdir', 'decimal(18,3)'),
 ('radiation', 'decimal(18,3)')]
```

They all match the original database schema.
But opening the parquet file with pandas I get:

```
df.dtypes:
idest                object
date         datetime64[ns]
temp                 object
hum                  object
prec                 object
wspeed               object
wdir                 object
radiation            object
dtype: object
```

I tried to change the datatype for one column using the customSchema option, the [doc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-jdbc.html) says Spark SQL types can be used:
*Users can specify the corresponding data types of Spark SQL instead of using the defaults.*

And FloatType is included in [Spark SQL datatypes](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-datatypes.html).

So I expect something like this should work:

```
custom_schema = "radiation FloatType"
conn_properties = {"driver": "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver",
                  "url": cfg.ORACLE_URL,
                  "query": 'select ... from .... ",
                  "customSchema": custom_schema
                  }
```

But I get this error

```
pyspark.sql.utils.ParseException: 
DataType floattype is not supported.(line 1, pos 10)

== SQL ==
radiation FloatType
```

I can’t find an option in the corresponding “write” method to specify the schema/types for the parquet DataFrameWriter.

Any idea how can I set the datatype mapping?

Thank you

Comment: try `radiation float`?

Comment: silly me, that's it, thank you!!